# Mysql WHERE IN() clause must sum duplicates occurences

Tags: mysql

I have a comma separated list of IDs that I have to use inside of an `IN()` clause in mysql (Percona Xtra DB), similar to this:

```
SELECT sum(p_views) as total_views FROM table WHERE id IN (1,1,3,5,5,5,7)
```

In the example above, the ids 1 and 5 will be summed only once, instead of the number of actual occurrences. The number of duplicates is unknown, and can range from 2 to 20000.

How would I have mysql treat them as unique numbers, and sum them accordingly no matter if they are all unique, or if the list is comprised of a single ID, 20000 times?

Comment: If you already have the same ID multiple times, what are the chances that you don't even need to run another query? Why not just sum them up from wherever you're starting from? What would running that query accomplish?

Comment: What about building a temporary table with id and occurences and join your table with this temporary table You could then `sum(t.p_views * tt.occurences)`.

Comment: Each ID has a piece of into attached to it. I need to sum that column as many times as it appears in the list of Ids to get the accurate data.

Comment: If Im using a temp table, I might as well use a JOIN that I used originally. I would like to avoid joining.

Comment: Why would you like to avoid joining? It's most times a very good idea to use a join.

Comment: why not just use a count of id's with a having clause?

Comment: Speed is the main reason. Its 4 JOIN queries, or 5 single table  queries, that are significantly faster.

Comment: what is this list of ID's? is it sent from another programming language?

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done with an `IN ()` predicate. That will only check whether a given row satisfies the predicate or not; it won't "duplicate" the rows returned.

To get "duplicate" rows returned (so values can be accumulated in a SUM() aggregate), you'd need another row source.

One option would be to use a JOIN operation to an inline view, instead of the `IN()` list predicate.

```
SELECT SUM(t.p_views) AS total_views
  FROM table t
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT           1 AS id 
       UNION ALL SELECT 1
       UNION ALL SELECT 1
       UNION ALL SELECT 3
       UNION ALL SELECT 5
       UNION ALL SELECT 5
       UNION ALL SELECT 5
       UNION ALL SELECT 7
     ) c
    ON c.id = t.id
```

Another (likely more efficient) option (if there are lots of repeated values) would be to use a "count" in place of repeating the values, and multiply, e.g.

```
SELECT SUM(t.p_views*c.cnt) AS total_views
  FROM table t
  JOIN
     ( SELECT           1 AS id, 2 AS cnt 
       UNION ALL SELECT 3      , 1
       UNION ALL SELECT 5      , 3
       UNION ALL SELECT 7      , 1
     ) c
    ON c.id = t.id
```

If this information is already available in another row source, you might be able to get improved performance by making use of that row source in the query (if an appropriate index is available), and avoid generating the messy "hardcoded" `UNION ALL` inline view, which won't be indexed (unless Percona has already implemented indexes for inline views.)

I'm sure there are other approaches.

But bottom line, it can't be done with an `IN()` list predicate. The results from a query with this:

```
WHERE id IN (1)
```

will be the same as results of a query with this:

```
WHERE id IN (1,1,1,1)
```

Because, for each row, both of those predicates will either evaluate to `TRUE`, `FALSE` or `NULL`. There's no way to return the "number of times" an item matched from an `IN()` comparison.

Comment: Yea, I saw the UNION solution, which is very messy. I'd have to pragmatically build these, and in some cases it will be hundreds/thousands of UNIONs

Comment: How are you "building" these? Do you have a rowsource that can give you this information? I think a `JOIN` operation is really the way to go here, just check the `EXPLAIN` output, and ensure suitable indexes are available. (With thousands of `UNION ALL SELECT`, it sounds like you might run into the `max_allowed_packet` limitation on the SQL statement.

Comment: Back to the JOIN query I go in that case. Thanks for clarifying.